# Fetch content from another website into a new one

Tags: views, 7, hooks

I want to fetch content from a website into another website. When I edit that content, it will automatically display changes. I am using Drupal 6.

Does anybody have an idea about I can achieve this?

Comment: Scrape, process, post.  All easily possible with Drupal.  Details about where data is coming from and where it is going would help improve answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module. It can import many different things into your Drupal site. I am using it to import RSS feeds as nodes.

Comment: I want to export the content too, and I want it done automatically.