# Fetch feed from a given URL

Tags: views, 6, feeds

I have a URL like www.example.com/test/rss.xml, and I want to import this XML automatically in Drupal 6. I created the content type as in rss.xml, but I am not able to import automatically. I tried the Feed module for this, but I am able to upload manually, not automatically, when I need it to update all the feeds from rss.xml automatically.

Does anybody have an idea about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/fetch-content-from-another-website-into-new

Comment: Not duplicate  .

Comment: @optimusprime619 I tend to agree it is a duplicate, in someway; the difference is only between fetching content, and fetching a feed content, where the first doesn't exclude the latter. Remember you can flag a question as duplicate using the "flag" link you see after the question, and before the comments. In the dialog box that appears, choose "it doesn't belong here" and then the reason for closing it (duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module?

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files